# Checking my libraries .js code with my libraries corresponding .d.ts code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a library written in JavaScript called `MyLibrary`. I'm also writing (and publishing) a corresponding type declaration file so TypeScript users can use my library in their TypeScript project. Here is my project structure:

```js
// myLibrary.js
function abc (x, y, z) {
  let a = 1
  return a + x + y + z
}

function f (a, b, c) {
  const v = abc(a, b, c)
  return v*v
}

module.exports = {
  abc,
  f
}
```

```js
// myLibrary.d.ts
export as namespace MyLibrary

export = MyLibrary

declare namespace MyLibrary {
  export function abc (x: number, y: number, z: number): number
}
```

This is pretty standard and works as expected. Now I'd like to improve the developer experience of MyLibrary. I want to be able to see the corresponding type declarations in my text editor when modifying the `.js` file. Below is a screenshot of VSCode with my cursor hovering over the `abc` function inside of `myLibrary.js`:
[image: ts intellisense of js file]
Notice how the editor shows `any` types for my `abc` function?

**How would I get it to show the declared types from my definition file?**

Is this a configuration with VSCode, `tsconfig.json`, or something else? Is this even possible?

Please keep in mind that rewriting my app as a `MyLibrary.ts` is not an option. I'm not using TypeScript to generate anything. It is apart of my project to support the TypeScript dev community.

Comment: I don't think its possible. Its probably possible to write a language server for it, but the default does not has this functionality. Probably because there is no good reason to do it. If you want to use the ts type definitions you should just use ts. The `.d.ts` is primarily to allow writing type definitions for third party libraries.

Comment: I would disagree with that there is no good reason to do this. Being able to provide both JS and TS developers an equivalent developer experience would be best for all parties involved. I guess I'll open an issue on the TypeScript repo as an official feature request.

Comment: I've opened a feature request on TypeScript GitHub project to hopefully get more context about this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30304

Comment: When you compile a typescript project, you can generate both JS files and typescript definition files. If you're providing a for others to use, typically these output files are what are shared - not the source files.